# Ignoring letters in user input C++

Tags: c++

A simplified version of my code:

```
vector<double> iV;
double i;
cout << "Enter numbers:\n";

while(cin >> i) {
    iV.push_back(i);
}

for (auto e : iV) {
    if (!iV.empty())
        cout << e << endl;
}
```

What this does right now is reads numbers in type double from cin, loads them into a vector, and prints them. However, the user must enter a letter to submit the input. **I don't want this.** I want any letters entered by the user to be ignored.

For example,

Enter numbers:
56 f 45.6 200.1 6g

Should have the output:
56
45.6
200.1
6

Comment: Checkout [`istream::clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) and [`istream::ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Comment: how does the user terminate input?

Comment: Would terminate input by typing ^Z

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could accept and upvote my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string process( const string& input ) // Removes all characters except <space>, '.' and digits
{
    string ret;
    for ( const auto& c : input )
    {
        if ( c == ' ' || c == '.' || ( c >= '0' && c <= '9' ) )
        {
            ret += c;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    string line;
    vector<double> iV;
    double i;
    while ( getline( cin, line ) )
    {
        line = process( line );
        stringstream ss( line );
        while ( ss >> i )
        {
            iV.push_back( i );
        }
    }

    for ( auto e : iV )
    {
        if ( !iV.empty() )
        {
            cout << e << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: process could also be written using `std::remove_if`. Might be easier to read.